# Issue in passing a JSON value to other class

Tags: getjson

I need to Pass JSON value to other class. But the Dictionary shows "`NULL`" value. I am using **NSURL Connection** in My Code

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection  {

NSDictionary *allDataDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webResponseData options:0 error:nil];

 NSLog(@"allDataDictionary = %@",allDataDictionary);

SecondViewController *a=[[SecondViewController alloc]init];

a.staticData=[allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"Customerlist"];
}

But the Dictionary shows "NULL" value.

Output Response:

{   "ReturnCode": "0",
    "Salesmanid": "",
    "Customerlist": [
        {
            "Customerid": "GENERAL CUSTOMER USD",
            "Customername": "Name of GENERAL CUSTOMER USD",
            "Contact": "123456",
            "Street1": "north street",
            "Street2": "south street",
            "City": "america",
            "Province": "",
            "Postal": "2343",
            "Country": "ZA",
            "Phone": "324567",
            "Mobile": "2323444555",
            "Email": "as@yahoo.co.in",
            "VetReg": "",
            "RegNo": "002",
            "LastUpdated": "2009-03-03T18:10:00"
        },
```

I need to parse these value to other class.anyone can help me?

Comment: Look at that "error" parameter where you pass NULL. What about passing the address of an NSError, and logging the error?

Comment: I got correct value in WebResponseData(NSData).If I pass it to NSDictionary,allDataDictionary shows null value.I checked using NSLog

Comment: You didn't on the call to NSJSONSerializer. "error:nil" should be "error:&myError".

Comment: I add NSError *error=nil; But i Got same response.I didn't get the output